# PHP: Custom parser for non-formatted text

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing

I am trying to create a project which will help students study various areas. The idea is that I have a piece of raw text, which contains quiz questions and answers which I want to parse as question header and answer options, which will be inserted into a database. However, the text is not properly formatted and due to the large amount of questions and answers (around ~20k per total), I cannot afford the time to manually insert them or format the text myself.

The raw text looks like this:

```
1. A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?

a) $44.44 b) $109.08 c) $118.80
d) $408.04 e) 
$444.40

2. When x = 3 and y = 5, by how much does the value of 3x2 – 2y exceed the value of 2x2 – 3y ?
a) 4
b) 14
c) 16
d) 20 e) 50
```

I tried creating my own PHP functions to parse the text properly, however I cannot get myself to get past the random line breaks, spaces, etc.

What I am trying to obtain:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["questionNumber"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["questionText"]=>
    string(175) "A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?"
    ["options"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(6) "$44.44"
      ["b"]=>
      string(7) "$109.08"
      ["c"]=>
      string(7) "$118.80"
      ["d"]=>
      string(7) "$408.04"
      ["e"]=>
      string(7) "$444.40"
    }
  }
}
```

The code I have so far:

```
$rawText = '1. A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?

a) $44.44 b) $109.08 c) $118.80
d) $408.04 e)
$444.40

2. When x = 3 and y = 5, by how much does the value of 3x2 – 2y exceed the value of 2x2 – 3y ?
a) 4
b) 14
c) 16
d) 20 e) 50
';

$rawTextLines = explode("\n", $rawText);
foreach ($rawTextLines as $lineNumber => $lineContents) {
    $lContents = trim($lineContents);

    if (empty ($lContents)) {
        unset ($rawTextLines[$lineNumber]);
    } else {
        $rawTextLines[$lineNumber] = $lContents;
    }
}

$processedQuestions    = array ();
$currentQuestionHeader = 0;
foreach ($rawTextLines as $lineNumber => $lineContents) {
    if (ctype_digit(substr($lineContents, 0, 1))) { // Question header
        $questionHeaderInformation = explode('.', $lineContents);
        $currentQuestionHeader     = $questionHeaderInformation[0];

        $processedQuestions[$currentQuestionHeader]['questionNumber'] = $currentQuestionHeader;
        $processedQuestions[$currentQuestionHeader]['questionText']   = $questionHeaderInformation[1];
    } else { // Question option
        $options = explode(')', $lineContents);

        if (count ($options) % 2 === 0) {
            $processedQuestions[$currentQuestionHeader]['options'][trim($options[0])] = ucfirst(trim($options[1]));
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Which produces this:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["questionNumber"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["questionText"]=>
    string(35) " A car averages 27 miles per gallon"
    ["options"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(8) "$44.44 b"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["questionNumber"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["questionText"]=>
    string(96) " When x = 3 and y = 5, by how much does the value of 3x2 – 2y exceed the value of 2x2 – 3y ?"
    ["options"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["b"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["c"]=>
      string(2) "16"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the current output does not match - not by far, what I am trying to obtain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: I am trying to write a function, or a series of functions that will produce the example output I provided above from the raw text using regex or any other way I can properly manipulate the text. As I mentioned, the raw text is not properly formatted and I cannot produce the correct output with my current knowledge.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hellow,

```html
^[0-9]+\. (.*)[\r\n]+a\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+b\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+c\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+d\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+e\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]*
```

[Try it !](https://regex101.com/r/XPsbde/3)

```
$re = '/^[0-9]+\. (.*)[\r\n]+a\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+b\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+c\)[\s]+(.*)    [\s]+d\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]+e\)[\s]+(.*)[\s]*/m';
$str = '1. A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon, which of the following is closest to how much the gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?

a) $44.44 b) $109.08 c) $118.80
d) $408.04 e) 
$444.40

2. When x = 3 and y = 5, by how much does the value of 3x2 – 2y exceed the value of 2x2 – 3y ?
a) 4
b) 14
c) 16
d) 20 e) 50';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: @Dreeeew Is it great ?